# Why are div wrapped images not dropping into corresponding divs with jQuery drop code?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I've been looking through this site and all of the jQuery examples I can find to get an answer, but can't seem to find something that matches closely enough. 
My html/css/script is located [here](http://cs.franklin.edu/~heinem01/quizpages/test.html).
I have four images (within divs), and four corresponding divs for the images to be dropped into. My images drag, and will drop anywhere on the page but in the the assigned div.
There are two scripts included on my test.html page. The first script causes the droppable divs to hight and change colors, but the second script I modified the basic jQuery assign script, but this code does not work at all (the boxes don't even highlight on hover or drop).

Here's the main script code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#ddt" ).draggable();
    $( "#ddt_droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: "#ddt",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
            }
        });

   $( "#plant" ).draggable();
    $( "#plant_droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: "#plant",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });

      $( "#beetle" ).draggable();
    $( "#beetle_droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: "#beetle",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });

      $( "#bird" ).draggable();
    $( "#bird_droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: "#bird",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

first set of CSS

```
#ddt{position:relative;float: right;width:100px;height:100px;left: 50px;top: 50px'}
#ddt_droppable{position: absolute;width:105px;height:150px;left: 50px;top:270px;}
```

relevant page code

```
<div id="ddt_droppable"></div>
<div id="plant_droppable"></div>
<div id="beetle_droppable"></div>
<div id="bird_droppable"></div>
<div id="plant" class="ui-widget-content">              
<img src="Plant.png" height="100" width="100" align="center" />
</div>
<div id="ddt" class="ui-widget-content">
<img src="DDT.png"  height="100" width="100" align="center"/>
 </div>
 <div id="beetle" class="ui-widget-content">
 <img src="Beetle.png" height="100" width="100" align="center"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `{` test.html:37, you might want to provide the relevant parts of your code

Comment: that should say sure thing! I edited the main post,adding it in there.

Comment: I see a typo at the top of your script `$function() {` should be `$(function() {`

Comment: Thanks Musa! I fixed that and now the images drop in the boxes! unfortunately they'll still drop in the wrong ones.

Comment: appears it might be a syntax issue? I've tried adding a revert to the draggable, and it causes all of the images to revert, even when dropped over their specified div box.